# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority when calling informatica server from .net WCF webservice on windows security update

Tags: wcf, informatica, .net-framework-version

We have hosted a ASP.net application in the server.

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.
.net FrameworK:MS .NET Framework 4.5.2

We do a informatica call from .net WCF Service.

Server team applied the below patches in the server. After the new patches are installed, we are not able do the informatica call.

Security patches applied:

Kb2954853 http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2954853 
Kb2978128 http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2978128

Error:
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'ifccu1infsa1.ifc.org:8446'.

Could you please help.

Comment: We are not able to make a  informatica call from a WCF service when Security patches are applied  Kb2954853  & Kb2978128